# How do I change the color of specific text in a contenteditable textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, ide

May someone please tell me how to get specifically set text to change color through Javascript in a textarea like a IDE does

```
<textarea placeholder="place code here">Put Scripts Here</textarea><script src="/editor/codelib.js"></script>
```

Comment: You would have to capture the text and wrap it inside html

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```html
<textarea onkeyup="checkWord(this)"></textarea>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
        function checkWord(word)
            {
                if (word.value == "hello" || "world") {
                    word.style.color='orange'
                } 
                else if (word.value == "!" || ".") {
                    world.style.color='red'
                }
                else {
                    word.style.color='#FFF'
                }
            }
```